# Moving background image increases in size as it moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve an effect where a given background image moves on a horizontal axis and repeats itself, giving this illusion effect of infinite looped images.

I am using HTML and CSS only and the issue is that over time, the background image increases in size and I don't know why. I think Javascript/Jquery has to be used here, but I'm novice and I'm pretty much stuck in progress and don't know a solution. Here's a codepen of what I have created so far.

https://codepen.io/Agnis/pen/aEQjPB

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundAnimate {
  from {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -10000px;
    top: -2000px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes backgroundAnimate {
  from {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -10000px;
    top: -2000px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes backgroundAnimate {
  from {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -10000px;
    top: -2000px;
  }
}

@keyframes backgroundAnimate {
  from {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -10000px;
    top: -2000px;
  }
}

#back {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/gF0ZHR/imageedit_2_8525438394.png);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 200s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  -o-animation-duration: 200s;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  animation-duration: 200s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#front {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/gF0ZHR/imageedit_2_8525438394.png) position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 300s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  -o-animation-duration: 300s;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: backgroundAnimate;
  animation-duration: 300s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="back"></div>
<div id="front"></div>
```

The desired effect is that the background image moves to the left and DOESN'T increase in size, which is the opposite of what happens now.

Any help? Much appreciated!

Comment: You do not need the `-moz` and `-o` prefixes, and I'm quite sure you can drop the `-webkit` too. This will make your code a whole lot simpler to read

Comment: It increases in size, because you used `background-size: cover`, _and_ you are changing the coordinates (top/left) of the element. Since width and height are auto, and right/bottom are 0, that of course increases the size of the element, and therefor naturally the background image set to cover it changes size with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because *it is* increasing. You use `background-position:cover;`, which makes the image always fill the element. If the element get twice as wide, the image will get twice as broad to match.

Your `<div id="back"></div>` is growing continuely, thus your BG is as well.

---

You can animate a background image. The code below is a quick example:

```
.elem{
    /* properties here */

    transition-property: background-position;
    transition-duration: 1s;

    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { background-position: -100%;}
    to {   background-position:    0%;}
}
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction! Thanks!! Going to accept in a few minutes since it doesn't let me now

Comment: Glad I could help, this problems are sneaky

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the left and top properties, effectively making the element bigger and bigger, and the background with it.

animate the background-position instead.

```
@keyframes backgroundAnimate {
  from {
    background-position: left top;
  }
  to {
    background-position:right bottom
  }
}
```

And you should get rid of all those unnecessary prefixes ;)